# Hibernate pom exception

Tags: hibernate, maven

I am getting following error when trying to execute the maven build:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hellohibernate: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.nsingh.hibernate:hellohibernate:war:1.0: Could not find artifact org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.5.4-Final in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

For the following pom :

```
<project>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <groupId>org.nsingh.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hellohibernate</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<build>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                                <warSourceDirectory>WebContect</warSourceDirectory>
                                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        </configuration>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer myself:

Add

`<type>pom</type>` to dependency.